# jQuery Mobile Style is not applied

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I have the below markup, injected dynamically. The `fieldcontain` is not styled.

```js
var markup = '';
markup += ('<div data-role="fieldcontain"><textarea cols="40" rows="4" name="" id="comment"></textarea></div><a data-role="button" href="#" id="updateComment" data-theme="b">Post Comment</a>');    
$('#fbCommentblock').empty().append(markup);
```

Comment: '<div data-role="fieldcontain"><textarea cols="40" rows="4" name="" id="comment"></textarea></div><a data-role="button" href="#" id="updateComment" data-theme="b">Post Comment</a>'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dynamically added content must be manually enhanced. Every jQuery mobile widget has unique function, for example listview has a method called:

```
$('#listviewID').listview('refresh');
```

But because I cant see what is that you are appending then use :

```
$('#contentId').trigger('create');
```

To will style dynamically added content added to a data-role="content" div tag.

If you want to find more about this theme read my blog article **[HERE](http://www.gajotres.net/jquery-mobile-and-how-to-enhance-the-markup-of-dynamically-added-content/)**. There you will find this theme described in detail with a lot of working examples.

Comment: Yes it must be used after the append. Take a look at a link I have posted in my answer, go to it and look for a chapter called: Enhance a page content. There you will find a working example.